# Set sprite image in Mobile

Tags: html, css, sprite

I´m using a sprite image in a project.

My html is:

```
<div class="image-step"><img src="icon-sprite.png")" /></div>
```

My CSS:

```
.image-step{width: 132px; height: 72px; display: block; margin: 0 auto 15px auto; overflow: hidden;}
.image-step img{position: relative; top: -41px;}
```

It looks good. My problem is in mobile, because I have to show that image in a small size.
I can put in media query 
.image-step{width: 62px;}
But I can´t set the Image to that size. If I use percentage, I´ll have problem when I modify mi image sprite.

Do you know how can I solve that problem?

Thank you.